# react native link break while loop in shell script

Tags: reactjs, shell, react-native, react-native-linking

There is a file like below

```
react-native-webrtc
react-native-randombytes
react-native-fs
react-native-callkeep
```

There is a shell script with two loop like below

```
while read line
do
    echo ${line}
done < './links.patch'

while read line
do
    react-native link ${line}
done < './links.patch'
```

First loop print each line working correctly, but second loop only link first one react-native-webrtc library then end loop. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Are you getting any error/output from the second loop?

Comment: @Tim No, it just linked first one library successful then end script

Comment: Maybe you can try `nohup react-native link ${line} &` inside your loop.